# Loading Application With Different Title on Load

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-express

Not sure if this is at all possible, but is there any way that, as soon as I start my application, that the title bar will change? So there is always a different title?

So, say my application title is called: `Test Application: Instance 1`, then ext time I load the application, the title will change to: `Test Application: Instance 2`, etc.

I am using `Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop`.

I have just started this project, so has the default form load function:

```
namespace Application
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work = `Form.load`

I don't know what else to try or if it is at all possible.

So, I don't know if it is possible, because how do you know when to stop it counting? Or maybe only stop once it hits 10 application hits?

Basically, I want the same form, but a different title name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a handler for the Load event on your main form and set the Text property to the title you desire:

```
string newTitle = MethodWhichGeneratesTitleText(); 
this.Text = newTitle;
```

In this method you can check your database, config file or other sources that help you determine the title you need.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't think this is going to work for what I want - need to "go back to the drawing board".

Comment: Whatever logic you use to determine the correct window title, this is the method to get the earliest update to the window title.